# Search file in only one project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

Is there a way how to search a file or class (I mean by Ctrl + Shift + T or R) only in some particular project and not in all workspace?I have Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: use the file search. There you can select where you want to search and what

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On `Menu` of `Ctrl + Shift + T or R` dialogue `Small down` arrow on extreme right use option `Select Working Set` then set the working set and you are done now you can only search files from selected working set.

```
Ctrl + Shift + T Or R
>Menu
 >Select Working Set
  >New
   >Java
     >Add Or Add All
      >Click on Selected Working set in Select Working set Dialog
        >Select Working set and you are done.
```

Comment: This is close but in my working set are like 12 projects (is a big Java EE app) so that won't help me

Comment: You can create multiple working sets and each working set can have 1 to n number of projects. So if you only want to search 1 project create working set of only 1 project

Comment: I've never seen or heard anyone having n working sets for n projects. Not to say that this would completely ruin their intended purpose.

Comment: Ok, this can me misunderstanding, by projects I ment pack of JAR and WAR files which creates Java EE app (in EAR file which is part of the workset too).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes. As the name suggests it is a set so it can be group of one or more. In his scenario It is perfectly fine to create a working set for this. Example was just to explain capablities of it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Select the project in project explorer -> Ctrl + H -> File Search Tab -> enter file name in containing text -> Check Selected Resources under Scope.

One more trick -> if you want to search only from *.java files then in File name patterns text box in the same File Search Tab enter *.java or *.props. This will filter out for you

Answer (score 1):

Click on file search
select enclosing projects under the subcategory 'scope'.
this will enable you to search inside a specific project

Answer (score 0):

For that you have the Search menu. You could use Search > File or Search > Java for that. In the search dialog, you can restrict the search scope as only the selected project, or as a predefined working set, as long as some additional options.

Comment: I know about this option but is not so convinient as searching through Ctrl+Shift+H so this is not the solution I am looking for. But maybe there is now way how to narrow the search except the workign sets